# Problem: Integrate using the Trigonometric Substitution method

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

***Exercise about Trigonometric Substitution***

[image: Exercise]

Objective: Resolve using the Trigonometric Substitution method.

I've already tried solving the exercise by taking the following steps:

1. I take e^x as 2sen(t) and I substitute.
2. Take dx as 2cos(t)dt.
3. After some easy straight-foward steps, I came out with this:
   [image]

The result has to be [image] and the integral of sen(t) is cos(t).

Answer (score 3):

In STEP 2: $\color{red}{e^x }dx=2\cos t\, dt$. so
$$\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{4-2e^{2x}}}\,dx =\int \frac{2\cos t}{2\cos t}\,dt=t+C=\arcsin\left(x/2\right)+C$$